# What kind of request rate limitations are there on IIS and ARR on IIS?

Tags: iis, arr

Title is pretty self explanatory. I wasn't able to find documentation on this online.. If someone knows or could point out some docs that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: IIS can only control bandwidth usage. If you want request throttling, you have to do that via a programming framework.

Comment: We're running into issues with multiple, rapid requests to the same PHP script on different servers. We are getting 403 errors for some of the requests that are occurring concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Is the  element you are looking for? The  element specifies that a remote client will be blocked if the number of requests received over a period of time exceeds a specific number.

[Deny by Request Rate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/dynamicipsecurity/denybyrequestrate)